# Can't edit with gksudo (Duplicate entry in source.list)

Tags: virtualbox, gksu

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://linuxhomeserverguide.com/server-config/VirtualBox.php).

And i have followed all the previous tutorials on this site to get where i am now. However now when i tried to install virtualbox i get some errors.

First and i ended up adding Virtual box sources twice.

How do I remove these duplicate entries? (Gksudo does not work. Cant edit the file)

When i try to run: `sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-4.0`

I get this error:

```
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-4.0 : Depends: libpython2.6 (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libhal1 (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: pdf-viewer
                  Recommends: python-central but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial you followed is pretty old. Indicates to Ubuntu 10.10 and Ubuntu 11.04 and interferes a debian source.

Ubuntu 10.10 is EOL from April 2012 and Ubuntu 11.04 will EOL soon (tomorrow :P )

Have a look here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Now , **to remove the duplicate entries**

to remove the duplicate entries (I suggest to remove any entry relative to VirtualBox) open gedit with root permissions with this command

`gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

If for any reason `gksudo` not working , you can use nano editor like this

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

With nano editor , when you complete your changes , save the changes with this keys

combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y(es)</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

After this , run in terminal

`sudo apt-get update` to update the sources.list

**Install Virtual-box**

Two versions of VirtualBox are available in Ubuntu. The first is the Open Source Edition and you can install it with this simple command in terminal

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose`

and the other is the closed source edition (preferred by many people) and you can download and install it from Oracle's website , here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

**Summary**

- Remove the duplicate entries
- Remove completely virtualbox with this command

`sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-*`

- Install virtualbox either from Ubuntu's repositories or from Oracle's website

**Further informations about VirtualBox installation and configuration can be found here:**

[Ubuntu community wiki - VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox)